# Is there an extension for Chrome to have a tab always jump to a certain scroll point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm quoting items from a vendor's page, but I don't want my customers to see it's another company's website.

Is there any way that I can have a tab always jumping to a specific scroll point on every page I open?
Maybe a Chrome or Mozilla extension?
I have searched, but maybe I'm phrasing my search wrong... or this is simply something that doesn't exist.

Comment: You could roll one with `window.scrollTo` but there are many other ways to get the content (such as an XHR request to that page and scrape the data you need). I would suggest updating your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just use a name anchor.

```
<a href="#quote"></a>
<a name="quote">"Around the quote."</a>
```

if you use windows.scrollTo you can still use the name anchor.